# Split a string using TCL

Tags: tcl

I'm a newbie to TCL and I'm trying to split the string below into a list:

```
Sep 20, 07:45:12, 100.1.1.1
```

My expectation is:

```
{Sep 20} {07:45:12} {100.1.1.1}
```

Could anyone help me with a simple solution ? I have my own way but it's a little bit complex
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a multicharacter separator sequence, it's easiest to use `string map` to convert it into a single rare character (something in the “unusual” part of Unicode will do; we'll use the escaped version of that) and then `split` on that. It's really a one-liner…

```
set theString "Sep 20, 07:45:12, 100.1.1.1"
set pieces [split [string map {", " \uffff} $theString] \uffff]
```

You can also use the `splitx` stuff in Tcllib for this, but it's overkill for this case.

Comment: The "splitx stuff" is documented here: http://core.tcl.tk/tcllib/doc/trunk/embedded/www/tcllib/files/modules/textutil/textutil_split.html

Answer (score 0):

```
% set foo "Sep 20, 07:45:12, 100.1.1.1"
Sep 20, 07:45:12, 100.1.1.1
% split [regsub -all {,\s+} $foo ,] ,    
{Sep 20} 07:45:12 100.1.1.1
%
```

Enclose any of the items with curly braces as needed, explicitly.
From TCL's perspective, it just a mechanism to show a space separated string. For e.g.,

```
% split "foo bar, bar bat, bat foo" ,
{foo bar} { bar bat} { bat foo}
%
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It's nice

Answer (score 0):

For completeness; requires Tcl 8.6+ (8.5 with the pure-Tcl add-on mentioned below):

```
set txt "Sep 20, 07:45:12, 100.1.1.1"
lmap item [split $txt ,] {string trim $item}
# => {Sep 20} 07:45:12 100.1.1.1
```

Documentation:
[lmap (for Tcl 8.5)](http://wiki.tcl.tk/40570),
[lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm),
[split](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/split.htm),
[string](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/string.htm)